# Regular expression for either or matching

Tags: java, regex

I have a string which could end with either

```
"/"
```

or

```
"/?secure=true"
```

I need to validate it. I tried this

```
\b(/(/?secure=true)?)\b
```

but I get no matches found with the regex.
However, with

```
^(/(\$secure=true)?)$
```

match is found. But this wont help in my case as the string that I want to validate will be prefixed with chars something like `"thisismystring/"` or `"thisismystring/?secure=true"`.

I want to know how to go about this.

Comment: Have you parsed the URL with URL/URI class? I suggest that you turn it into URL or URI first before doing any validation.

Comment: Your last example is correct, just remove the ^ from the beginning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both cases would contain the

```
/
```

So that should not be in the optional part.

You put the optional part in ()?

and escape the question mark with backslash

```
/(\?secure=true)?
```

And to indicate that it should end with that, you put $ at the end

```
/(\?secure=true)?$
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the pipe symbol (|) to specify an or:

```
(/|/\?secure=true)$
```

You also need to escape the question mark, as here, and should specify the "$" for end of string but not the "^" for start of string.

Comment: but this matches this as well:  thisismystring/&secure=true

Answer (score 1):

Can be done like this:

```
/(\?secure=true)?$
```